# Custom delete method on queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

My Django model has custom logic in the `delete` method. Therefore since I wane to make sure that this logic [is called when I call delete on my `queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects), I wrote my own `queryset` delete.

```
class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):
    # Do we have to be any fancier here?
    def delete(self):
        for m in self:
            m.delete()
```

and my question is do I have to do anything fancier than iterating and calling `delete` on each instance?

Comment: Note that this is really inefficient; the point of the queryset delete method is that it does a single delete query against the db, whereas this will do one query per record.

Comment: I understand but in this case the additional delete logic is expensive anyways. Also there are places in contrib that use the queryset so not catching the delete call causes issues for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should clear the result cache so if the queryset will be reused then DB query will be evaluated again.

Also you have to set two attributes:

- `alters_data=True` prevents calling this method from templates;
- `queryset_only=True` hides this method from queryset used as manager.

  class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):

  ```
  def delete(self):
      for m in self:
          m.delete()
      self._result_cache = None    
  delete.alters_data = True
  delete.queryset_only = True
  ```