# Cascading Delete w/ Custom Model Delete Method

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a custom `delete` method on my `Model` that I make sure is called correctly when calling `delete` on the QuerySet by using:
[Custom delete method on queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127828/custom-delete-method-on-queryset).

This does not seem to work when Django performs a cascading delete. In that case, the ORM calls `_raw_delete` on a regular `QuerySet` thereby bypassing my custom delete method.

How do I prevent that from happening?

The issue seems to be caused because this uses `_base_manager` rather than `_default_manager`:

```
def related_objects(self, related, objs):
  return related.related_model._base_manager.using(self.using).filter(
      **{"%s__in" % related.field.name: objs}
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I need to add this to the `QuerySet`:

```
 def _raw_delete(self, using):
        self.delete()
    _raw_delete.alters_data = True
```

and set `use_for_related_fields = True` on the `Manager`.