# How to implement soft delete in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model and I have implemented soft delete in it. but while deleting from Django admin, it is deleting from the database. How will I bring soft delete in the Django admin also?

by soft delete what I meant is without deleting the data from the DB, a boolean-field "is_deleted" in the model is set to 1"

```
class Model_1(models.Model):
field_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
.
.
is_active = models.booleanField(default=1)
is_deleted = models.booleanField(default = 0)

class modelForm_1(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Model_1
        exclude = ("field_1", "field_2", "field_3",)

class ModelAdmin_1(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Model_1
    list_display = ("jobid", "job_title", "position", "employer")
    change_form_template = 'admin_panel/detail.html'
    form = modelForm_1

admin.site.register(Model_1, ModelAdmin_1)
```

Comment: What does "soft delete" mean to you? How did you implement it?

Comment: Can you share the Model_1 class?

Comment: I have made the changes. please check now.

Comment: Check out this question and its answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213991/soft-deleting-objects-in-django

Does that help your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **base abstract model** with is_deleted boolean and a **manager** to list only the non deleted objects.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def delete(self):
        self.is_deleted = True
        self.save()
```

Inherit  the base model

```
class Model_1(BaseModel):

   field_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
   
   objects = BaseModelManager()
```

Add a model manager to filter only non deleted data.

```
class BaseModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)
```

So by doing this when the objects are deleted through the admin, they won't actually be removed from the database; instead, they will simply no longer appear in the list view.